# What type does auto use for containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, auto

I can achieve identical output by using different containers in C++. For example . .

```
    std::array<int, 5> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
```

or

```
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

or

```
    int v[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

etc . .

So what container does `auto` use here?

```
    auto v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::initializer_list<int>`

---

Not that hard to check for yourself, you can always `decltype(v)`, and then compare it with said list type.

That has another nice property, that sometimes is very useful and might interest you:

```
for (auto i : {1,2,3,4,5})
    std::cout << i << ", ";
```

It can be done because `initializer_list` keeps the standard range interface.

Comment: `<tomalak> << TYPE_DESC(v); auto v = {1,2,3,4,5};` / `<geordi> lvalue initializer_list<int>` Correct. +1

Comment: Two little remarks: Strictly speaking, `initializer_list` is not a container in the sense of the standard. Your example works, because the standard explicitely defines ranged-based for statements of that form. At first sight there is no entity of type `initializer_list`. Such an object is introduced implicitely, so you have to include `<initializer_list>`, but you cannot "see" it.